# How can I monitor Facsimile/400 and know when it stops sending faxes?

Tags: fax, rpgle, ibm-midrange

here's my situation:

We are using Facsimile/400 on a IBM System i and sometimes it just stops sending faxes. Everything seems in order but the faxes just pile up with a "Sending" status.

This is an intermittent problem that cannot be provoked manually so I want to come up with a program that checks that the fax is still running.

Here are the problem's symptoms when it happens:

- In `CHKFAXSTS`, all the faxes have the "Sending" status
- The `QFFSNDFAX` output queue is empty
- The `QFFSNDERR` output queue is filled with the currently sending faxes and the previous faxes in error

**Now how can I know that the fax is still sending faxes?**

I can get the list of the spooled files in `QFFSNDERR` and check if a spooled file is lingering there too long, but how can I know it's status is "Sending"? - I don't want to catch the faxes that have a wrong fax number etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the approach I used:

I found the table `QUSRSYS/QAFQSND`, which contains the complete list of faxes as they can be seen in `CHKFAXSTS`.

With a SQL query, I can now check if there are faxes on the "Sending" status for too long.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for a solution try asking on the [MIDRANGE-L mailing list](http://murl.me/midrangel)